# Adding .dll to java build path

Tags: java, eclipse, dll

I'm using a .jar library that needs additional .dll or .so to function.
I copied them in a folder in my eclipse project and then added that folder to the native library location in Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries. When I start my application in eclipse, it works well but when I export it as a runnable jar and then execute it, it doesnt work anymore and gives me a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError error.

Is there a possibility to add these additional files inside the .jar and also add them to the  java.library.path variable when running the application?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating new resources folder in Eclipse (if you are using it, since that folder will be on classpath), or just add it manually to classpath.

Comment: well if i do that, the path still has to be assigned to java.library.path, and i don't know how to do that. (btw. ive tried adding a resource folder already)

Comment: Are you using eclipse?